# UIImageViews's not responding to touch event after application returns to the foreground

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uitouch

My application consists of a grid of `UIImageView`'s that respond to touch events. If I switch to another application, then switch back to mine, the `UIImageView`'s no longer seem to respond to touches. Would this be something to do with my `touchesBegan` method? My method is declared like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];

 .....
 ...

}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts about what's causing my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you implementing this method? In the parent view of all the UIImageViews or in a subclass of UIImageView?

Comment: Hmmm... have you tried dropping an NSLog() inside the touchesBegan method to see if that method is even being fired anymore?

Comment: Ah I hadn't thought to do that. I added an NSLog() and the method does still seem to be firing...

Comment: Well it must be an issue with your image views. What are they supposed to do in this method? Maybe your view controller isn't referencing them strongly and they are being purged from memory when the app enters the background.

Comment: They have an image assigned to them, and then that image changes when they're pressed. I tried changing my .h file so they're referenced strongly, but that didn't seem to change anything...

Comment: My `UIImageView`s and `UIImage`s are stored in `NSMutableArray`s. Could it be something to do with the arrays?